# Java Hadoop: is it possible to read the contents of a file only once?

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a file where I store some data, this data should be used by every mapper for some calculations.

I know how to read the data from the file and this can be done inside the mapper function, however, this data is the same for every mapper so I would like to store it somewhere(variable) before the mapping process beings and then use the contents in the mappers.

if I do this in the map function and have for example a file with 10 lines as input, then the map function will be called 10 times, correct? so if I read the file contents in the map function I will read it 10 times which is unnecessary

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because many of your Mappers run inside of a different JVM (and possibly on different machines), you cannot read the data into your application once prior to submitting it to Hadoop.  However, you can use the [Distributed Cache](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) to "Distribute application-specific large, read-only files efficiently."

As per that link:  "Its efficiency stems from the fact that the files are only copied once per job and the ability to cache archives which are un-archived on the slaves."

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you want to call only 1 function to read all the lines in a file. Assuming yes, here is my view on it.

The mapper allows you to read 1 line at a time for safety sake so that you can control how many lines of input to read. And this takes a certain amount of memory. For one example, what if the file is large like 1GB size. Are you willing to read all the contents? This will take up a considerable amount of memory and have impact on the performance.
This is the safety aspect that I mentioned earlier.

My conclusion is that there is no Mapper function that reads all the contents of a file.
Do you agree?